# Ultimo Registro por data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Como faço para retornar a atualização mais recente de um registro
exemplo o registro pode ter vários status em um dia porém preciso retornar o mais recente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode utilizar do ORDER BY nas clounas de Hora e hora fim: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Answer (score 1):

Para trazer a maior hora_fim de cada data use:

```
SELECT Ordem, Hora, MAX(hora_fim), status FROM sua_tabela
GROUP BY Hora
ORDER BY Hora;
```

O select acima só funcionará no MySQL se o modo SQL `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` estiver desativado.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela
WHERE ordem = numero da orem
ORDER BY Hora DESC, horafim DESC
LIMIT 1;
```